# My php code is keep getting disable in wordpress editor after upgraded into latest version

Tags: php, wordpress

My website had a older version of wordpress. Recently I upgraded it to the latest version. After that my php code what I write in the editor is keep getting disabled.

The old page which has php code in ti still works. Although in the editor the php codes are disabled. But if I try to save that it stops working. So i cannot update those page. And also I cannot create new page with php code in it

Exec-PHP plugin is installed.

If I write

```
<?php echo $c; ?>
```

It converts into

```
<!--?php echo $c; ?-->
```

How to fix that

attached image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I knew this question will be asked. . Well this is not the only case where I need to write php code.  Even if I can write shortcode without php ; I need other php code to write. I have used this line just as an example. because its short and esy to understand. But ultimately i need a solution to write php code.

Comment: You can just use shortocode without the php tags in editor

Comment: Turning this into a comment seems to be a feature of the editor component in WP, because if I try and insert that as text I get the same result, without even having any such plugin installed. I would suggest that you go ask the plugin author for support first of all, whether they know anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for responding.

Apparently I find the solution by installing the Classic Editor plugin

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

It prevents disabling the php code.

If you are facing similar problem you can try this one

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which I don't quite recommend, is to follow this direction:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/exec-php-to-work-in-php-7-needs-this/

This is basically updating the actual plugin, which will surely be overwritten by their next update.

This plugin requires a number of changes to work with php 7.

In exec-php.php

```
$GLOBALS[‘g_execphp_manager’] =& new ExecPhp_Manager();
```

must be changed to

```
$GLOBALS[‘g_execphp_manager’] = new ExecPhp_Manager();
```

In includes/manager.php from line 36
change each =& to =

In includes/admin.php lines 53,56,57,63,64,79 change =& to =

In includes/cache.php line 22,39 change =& to =

In includes/ajax.php line 64 change =& to =

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the plugin you use for this. However, I use `xyzscripts` for the same cause. It creates `short-codes` for me to use.

Here is an example:

1. Create your PHP code and get a Tracking Name.
   [image: PHP Editor]
2. You will then get your `short-code` as below, note the Tracking Name.
   [image: Short-codes List]

I personally think this is the best way as it allows re-usability and centralized location to update all your scripts.

[XYZ WP PHP Code Download and Documentation](https://xyzscripts.com/wordpress-plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/details)